# Excel Query Pulling from Oracle Occasionally Fails (ODBC error) How to fix?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have an Excel file that runs a SQL query from an Oracle database and is set up to refresh all data sources every 15 minutes. The file runs perfectly fine 95% of the time, properly executing and pulling the data needed.

Occasionally a box stating "Select Data Source" will pop up (seen below) where, if we select the Oracle_to_Excel connection and hit "ok", the queries execute properly again, but after each refresh, the box will pop up again requiring us to once again hit the Oracle_to_Excel connection and "ok". However, if we close down the file, re-open it, and start the refresh cycles again (just a macro that refreshes all connections ever 15 minutes) the "Select Data Source" box doesn't show up again. Sometimes we can go days without this occurring, other times it's only a couple of hours.

Is there any way I can prevent the "Select Data Source" box from appearing (either by fixing my Data Source Connection or changing how the query is ran) or is there a line of code I can throw into my VBA that essentially says "If 'Select Data Source' would appear GOTO Exception" where I could write up a VBA code to close the file, re-open it, and reset the refresh macro.

[image]

Comment: *or is there a line of code I can throw into my VBA* ... where is your VBA?

Comment: My VBA is basically just 
Sub Cycle1()
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "Cycle1"
endsub

Comment: Are you using QueryTables or PivotTable? How is the every 15 mins. being run?

Comment: I believe I am using QueryTables and I have a macro that basically looks like  Sub Cycle1() ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "Cycle1" endsub